# How to manage two forms with one javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript but I still do not get to the book's chapter that could answers my question, so I will be very grateful if somebody can put me in the right track.

Here is the situation:

I am using jquery to submit a form. However I need to put two forms (of the same kind but referring to different object) and I want to use the same jquery function to submit the one I choose.

This is the jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".submit").click(function(){
   var name = $("#student").val();
   var mark = $("#mark").val();
    var dataString = 'student='+ student + '&mark=' + mark;

   $.ajax
   ({
       type: "POST",
      url: "records.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function()
      {
          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
         $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
      }
   });

   return false;
});
});
</script>
```

These are the forms I would like to pass to the above function depending on the one I click.

```
<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student" value="Mandy" > 
Mark: <input size="2" id="mark" name="mark" value="1" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>  
</form> 

<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="hidden" id="student" name="student" value="Fred" > 
Mark: <input size="2" id="mark" name="mark" value="1" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>  
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: You have repeating ID's, which is going to cause problems. ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: What is your issue? Did anything work, not work etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first thing's first - you're going to get nowhere with the same id's on the page. Change the id's on `student` and `mark` to classes (which do not have to be unique):

```
<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="hidden" class="student" name="student" value="Mandy" > 
Mark: <input size="2" class="mark" name="mark" value="1" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>  
</form> 

<form method="post" name="form">
<input type="hidden" class="student" name="student" value="Fred" > 
Mark: <input size="2" class="mark" name="mark" value="1" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>  
</form>
```

Then the jQuery is pretty simple - find the nearest form and seek out the student and mark by class (scoped to the form):

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
   var $form = $(this).closest('form');
   var student = $(".student", $form).val();
   var mark = $(".mark", $form).val();
    var dataString = 'student='+ student + '&mark=' + mark;

   $.ajax
   ({
       type: "POST",
      url: "records.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function()
      {
          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
         $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
      }
   });

   return false;
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lc8R/